# How do I format the output of my MATLAB command window?

Tags: matlab, io, printf, rounding, data-representation

Currently looking at this API page, I have tried inputting `format loose` and `format compact`, but to no avail. What I need to do is change the way this number is displayed on the command window:

[image]

I obtain the value by rounding it to the three most significant figures in the function which I call from my main function.

```
stat = round(mean(v_stat),3,'significant');
```

I display the values through this statement:

```
fprintf('Ratio of Compression for Blind Deconvolution: %d \n',stat1);
```

I need to know how to display this value as as it's proper state instead of being multiplied by *e* raised to power of something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your format statement, e.g. (a float with 3 decimals).

```
fprintf('Ratio of Compression for Blind Deconvolution: %.3f \n',stat1);
```

see the [matlab help for fprintf](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to understand more on the format api.

Note: the `%d` your using is for integers

Comment: If you are outputting to the command line and not to a file then it probably makes more sense to use `sprintf` than `fprintf`

Comment: @Dan - Each to their own but I would disagree.  `sprintf` saves the string in a matlab variable - which you can display by not using a`;` or use `disp` (note `mlint` will suggest that `fprintf` can normally be used instead) on the variable.   `fprintf` with no numerical input will by default write to the command line and if you use `fprintf ( 2, 'your string\n' )` - it will write to the command line in red text which can be useful to highlight to the user.